# Javascript pop up that will fade away

Tags: javascript

I need to have a message box like thing (but with no buttons), that would display on the screen saying `All data was saved` and then fades away in 2-3 seconds.

It's like an alert, where we are alerting the user that the records have been saved. But i need it to display in a small box on top of the screen and it should fade out.

Can someone help me with a javascript code that would do this ?

Sorry, i have any code, and hope i made my question clear.

Comment: Are you using a library like jQuery or is this just pure javascript?

Comment: If you limit your scope and take the "fade out" part away, doing this in pure javascript gets a bit easier. jQuery is still highly recommended if you're allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*** *EDIT* ***

OP has since clarified that they are not currently using jQuery ... but since doing JS animations by hand is non-trivial, I would suggest that the OP should start using jQUery in order to solve this problem (not to mention all the other great uses of the library).  See comments for details.

*** *END EDIT* ***

Won't write your code for you, but if you're using jQuery you probably want to look in to fadeOut: http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

With it you can do something like:

```
$('body').append('<div id="alert">ALL data was saved</div>');
$('#alert').fadeOut('slow')
```